# How to locate the LOAD MORE button using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to locate the path for a "Load More Button" on this site I am trying to scrape.

https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all

The button html:

```
<a class="button" href="?gender=All&amp;search=&amp;page=1" title="Load more items" 
 rel="next">Load More</a>  
 "Load More" == $0
 ::after == 0$
```

Comment: Can you share a link to that page? A single element HTML is not enough here

Comment: Does the website show  the button you are looking when the page loads or do you have to interact with something to make the button pop up

Comment: try XPATH of: //a[text()='Load More']

Comment: https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all

Comment: What locators have you tried and what was the result? You haven't provided any code to demonstrate your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element <kbd>LOAD MORE</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Load more items']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Load more items']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any attempts and I can see 3 right off the top of my head that should work...

1. CSS selector, `a[title='Load more items']`
2. XPath, `//a[text()='Load More']`
3. By link text, "Load More"

In general you should prefer CSS selectors because they are more widely supported, faster, and have simpler syntax.

Answer (score 0):

this is the XPATH for that button that you want
you can right-click on an element to inspect and right-click on it to copy XPath

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ' //*[@id="block- 
 mainpagecontent"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/a').click()
```